"PGRST202" error in weweb - UPDATE function in Supabase
im working in weweb where im trying to call simple function to add logo url from another table stored in Supabase.
Error im getting:
code: "PGRST202"
details: "Searched for the function public.cars without parameters or with a single unnamed json/jsonb parameter, but no matches were found in the schema cache."
Code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cars(icon text) RETURNS void AS $$;
UPDATE main_reservations
SET icon = (SELECT logos.link
  FROM logos
  WHERE lower(main_reservations.model) = lower(logos.model_name));
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks
I guess I need to define something? Sorry if Im wrong Im complete begginer
